# "@EnableWebMvc" 、"PUT" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" leads to MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

**version**

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.15</version>
 <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

**Controller**

```
@PutMapping("/test3") 
public String test3(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("k") int k){
 return id+","+k;
}
@PostMapping("/test2") 
public String test2(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("k") int k){
 return id+","+k;
}
```

1. @EnableWebMvc and "PUT" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data in body,it's will MissingServletRequestParameterException.
2. But @EnableWebMvc and "POST" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data in body everything is ok.
3. Remove @EnableWebMvc ,"PUT" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data in body everything is ok.

**test data**

```
curl -XPUT  -d "id=AA&k=123" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  localhost:8000/test3

curl -XPOST  -d "id=AA&k=123" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  localhost:8000/test2
```

tks!

Comment: When using Spring Boot don't use `@EnableWebMvc` as this disables large parts of the web autoconfiguraiton that Spring Boot does (as you noticed). One of them is registering the `FormContentFilter` to be able to access the body in requests other then POST.

Comment: In this project I have to use @EnableWebMvc, otherwise there will be other problems(such as :Swagger 3.0、custom AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver)

Comment: No you don't need `@EnableWebMvc` you need an `WebMvcConfigurer` to add the argumenbt resolver. One doesn't need to other so no you should not use `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: I'll give it a try,thinks!